# Choose Solution type in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new xamarin.forms framework, When I started to work for cross platform application for making new solution (new solution->mobile apps), I got following three options for moving further:

1. Blank App(Xamarin.Forms Portable)
2. Blank App(Xamarin.Forms Shared)
3. Class Library(Xamarin.Forms Portable)

After investigating a lot, among those i did not create any difference. Can anyone tell me the difference with example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin has the answer to your question [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/), but I'll give you a short rundown here as well.

- Class Library(Xamarin.Forms Portable)

  - Is an Portable Class Library you can put classes in, which would then be usable by either an Android, iOS or WP app.
- Blank App(Xamarin.Forms Portable)

  - Creates a set of apps for Android, iOS and possibly WP using a Portable Class Library for the common parts
- Blank App(Xamarin.Forms Shared)

  - Creates a set of apps for Android, iOS and possibly WP using a Shared Library for the common parts

The difference between [PCL](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/) and [Shared](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/) is that a PCL library is compiled once, and then referenced as a library by each app. A Shared library is compiled directly into each app (and is thus compiled three times as opposed to one for the PCL)

Comment: theoretically I can understand what you told me but I am unable to understand usage of these options can you give any example for those.

Comment: Not really, you put the same code in both of them - it's mostly a matter of taste I guess. Shared libraries do offer the possibility of using conditional compilation, which I actively try to avoid since I've found it error prone. Try them both out and see which one you like the best.

Comment: so according to you Blank App (Xamarin.forms Portable) is the best option for making cross platform application?

Comment: Yeah, but as I said - you should try both and see for yourself :p

Comment: Yeah i will try both.

Comment: hey fredrik, If you don't mine can i ask some thing ?

Comment: Sure, join me in [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70998/private-discussion)

Comment: sorry fredrik my reputation is less than 20 so that can't participate in private chat.

Comment: is any other option to talk..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70999/discussion-between-vinit-saxena-and-fredrik).